# how can i get last updated value of ''While'' loop after removing all previous data

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, while-loop

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time


url = 'https://www.internetlivestats.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/vimal/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/win32/91.0.4472.101/chromedriver.exe')


def parseprice():
    try:
        driver.get(url)

    except:
        print('Network error or url error')
        driver.quit()
    price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="rts-counter"]').text
    return price

while True:
    result= str(parseprice())
    print(result)
```

result is keep comming one by one we need last value which is updated ,,

can anybody help us to sort this

Comment: you can have a counter, and in `parseprice` method, if it `driver.get(url)` is succeeded then you can have a assert and return the value and based on that value you can break the while loop.

Comment: i tried with so its not workiing

Comment: tried but no result even no error msg too